# Pe file code starting address

Tags: ida, windows, pe, executable

When i load an `exe` in the *IDA* the assembled code always starts at `00401000` address. Does it mean that in `pe` files the code always starts at that specific address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your entrypoint is 0x1000, and your base is 0x00400000, use a tool that allows you to view the AddressOfEntryPoint attribute you see value 0x1000, Your program's EntryPoint address is made up of ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint, this is the starting point for running your software.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not  all pe files do not start at the same  address 0x401000
[historically 0x400000 is the ImageBaseAddress](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141003-00/?p=43923) Header is 0x1000 bytes
so .code section starts at 0x401000  for a normal exe

since the Exe's module is the first to be loaded it normally gets its Preferred ImageBase Address

but a relocation table is a part of exe in case there is a conflict and the imagebase needs to be shifted to another base

you can control both aspects  using linker switches

```
C:\>link /? | grep -iE "base|fixed"
      /BASE:{address[,size]|@filename,key}
      /DYNAMICBASE[:NO]
      /FIXED[:NO]
```

you can also lookup about rebasing in ida